# Java importing .class files

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been given two .class files. Using Netbeans, I created a folder in my src to import my classes.

Once I've got my classes in the right directory I add my class folder to the project sources:
-Project.
-Properties.
-Sources.
-Add folder.
-Class folder.

Then confirmed all sources are up to date:
-> Source
-> Scan for external changes

I then construct a new instance of the class in my source code, but am given an error message: "cannot find symbol"

I've successfully Imported the .class files in Eclipse but I don't like the Eclipse UI and would like to stick with Netbeans.

Comment: Thanks for the status update. But where is the question?

Comment: The question is what I'm doing wrong configuring the .class files in Netbeans...

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to put those .class files into the "project sources."  The IDE will expect to find .java files in there.

You want to add your .class files as a dependency somehow.  Is there a way to configure the classpath in Netbeans?  (I imagine there is.)  Look for a way to add a folder to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this with Netbeans is to create a class library and then compile it as a jar so that your other project knows how to use it. Once done you can add then add that jar to your project without issue like you would with any other library.

**Step 1**: In netbeans create a new `Java Class Library` project.

**Step 2**: Drag and drop the `.class` files into your new class library in netbeans, or drop them into the src folder and reload the project.

**Step 3**: Compile the class library project so that it packages it as a .jar file.

**Step 4**: Drag the complied jar file into your existing netbeans project, or add it as a library.

**Done**: You can now use the packaged/complied class files like any normal jar you have imported into your project.

See here for an example I found with some screen shots:
http://featurenotbug.com/2009/06/adding-a-class-file-to-your-java-project/